# Cassandra database design with long row

Tags: database-design, cassandra

I have project I need to move from mongodb to cassandra.

Problem is I have query that selects last 1000 "items" sorted by insert time. This is like "select item from x order by created desc"

The way I can do this is to have all items (or item numbers) on single row. However new items are inserted all the time. From the other side, I do not need more than 1000-2000 items.

Any idea how this can be designed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can query a limited number of items sorted by insert time by making insert time a clustering key and using the ORDER BY and LIMIT keywords in your query. Read more [here](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.0/cql/ddl/ddl_compound_keys_c.html). You can also choose to have the [clustering key sorted](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_reference/refClstrOrdr.html) in descending order on disk (default will be ascending) to make those queries more efficient.